# ISNULL with COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ agent ║ prime ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ Said  ║ 100   ║
║ Farid ║ 200   ║
║ Walid ║ 150   ║
║ Said  ║ 300   ║
║ Said  ║ 250   ║
║ Said  ║ 400   ║
║ Farid ║ 300   ║
║ Farid ║ 250   ║
║ Walid ║ 140   ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

Query

```
select  agent, ISNULL(count(*),0) as NB from [agents]
where prime >= 200
group by agent
```

The output:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ agent ║ prime ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ Farid ║     3 ║
║ Said  ║     3 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

I want to replace the null value with 0 because as you can see the agent 'walid' have no prime >= 200. The results I want to achieve:

```
agent   prime
Farid   3
Said    3
Walid   0
```

I know Its achievable using a `UNION` but I want to know why this ISNULL is not functional in this case and If its possible to do.

Comment: Aside: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your where clause filters Walid from your result set entirely.  Try this approach instead:

```
select agent, sum(case when prime >= 200 then 1 else 0 end) as NB
from [agents]
group by agent
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `where` clause filters everything out.  You can accomplish what you want using conditional aggregation:

```
select agent, sum(case when prime >= 200 then 1 else 0 end) as nb
from agents
group by agent;
```

As a hint:  `count(*)` does not return `NULL`.  It returns `0`, so there is no need to use `COALESCE()` (or similar logic).

Comment: I believe you meant what `Brandon` just mentioned because this query doesn't achieve what I'm looking for. In fact, I'm having a syntax error for some reasons (in the brackets of the first line)

Comment: @user3832856 . . . I missed the SQL Server tag.  I thought the question was tagged MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `NVL` in place of `ISNULL`. It should give you the desired result I guess.

Comment: I believe that's the equivalent of `ISNULL` in `Oracle` and doesn't work in SQL Server